# How to use ZoomableDraweeView of Fresco

Tags: android, image, fresco

The image is unable to load, I am using the ZoomableDraweeView. I copied the sources from fresco's samples github repo and implemented it using this snippet

```
ZoomableDraweeView view = (ZoomableDraweeView) v.findViewById(R.id.photoDraweeView);
DraweeController ctrl = Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder().setUri(
    Uri.parse(photoUrl)).setTapToRetryEnabled(true).build();
GenericDraweeHierarchy hierarchy = new GenericDraweeHierarchyBuilder(getResources())
    .setActualImageScaleType(ScalingUtils.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER)
    .setProgressBarImage(new ProgressBarDrawable())
    .build();
view.setController(ctrl);
view.setHierarchy(hierarchy);
```

Unfortunately the Image doesn't load.

I already tried it with SimpleDraweeView and it works fine.

Comment: Have you looked at the logcat output as suggested in the Troubleshooting section of the Fresco documentation?
http://frescolib.org/docs/troubleshooting.html#_